# Trouble with linq left join only including values that are a match

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following code

```
public async Task<List<UserBasicViewModel>> FindUsersWithFriendshipStatusAsync(
        Guid userId, 
        string searchValue, 
        int skip, 
        int take)
    {
        var db = DbMakeLocalInstance;
        var userQuery = 
            from user in db.Users
            where (user.FirstName.StartsWith(searchValue)
                   || user.LastName.StartsWith(searchValue)
                   || user.Name.StartsWith(searchValue)
                   || user.School.StartsWith(searchValue)
                   || user.SchoolClass.StartsWith(searchValue))
                   && user.UserId != userId
            join status in db.Friendship on user.UserId equals status.FriendUserId into fstatus
            from status in fstatus.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where status.UserId == userId
            select new {User = user, Status = status};
        var query2 = await (userQuery.OrderBy(u => u.User.Name)
            .Skip(skip)
            .Take(take)
            .ToListAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false));

        var users = query2.Select(u => new UserBasicViewModel(u.User, u.Status)).ToList();
        return users;
    }
```

which is supposed to give me all the users that matches the search query and the friendship status if it exist with the supplied `userId`.

The problem is that it returns only users where there already exist a relation between the current `userId` and the users that are matches on the search query. I want the users that match the search query without any matches in friendship as well.

Please help!

Comment: You can't have `where status.UserId == userId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
var userQuery = 
        from user in db.Users
        where (user.FirstName.StartsWith(searchValue)
               || user.LastName.StartsWith(searchValue)
               || user.Name.StartsWith(searchValue)
               || user.School.StartsWith(searchValue)
               || user.SchoolClass.StartsWith(searchValue))
               && user.UserId != userId
        select new {
            User = user,

            // I'm using single because I'm guessing there's only one match
            Status = db.Friendship
                .Where(f => f.FriendUserId == user.UserId && f.UserId == userId)
                .SingleOrDefault(),
        };
```

Comment: `SingleOrDefault()` made it crash so had to change it to `FirstOrDefault()`, but otherwise perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could check equality between status.UserId and userId before left join.

```
    from user in db.Users
    where (user.FirstName.StartsWith(searchValue)
           || user.LastName.StartsWith(searchValue)
           || user.Name.StartsWith(searchValue)
           || user.School.StartsWith(searchValue)
           || user.SchoolClass.StartsWith(searchValue))
           && user.UserId != userId
    join status in db.Friendship on new {user.UserId, searchUserId = userId} equals 
                                    new {UserId = status.FriendUserId, searchUserId = status.UserId} into fstatus
    from status in fstatus.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {User = user, Status = status};
```